# Использование active_objects

Tags: python, django

Информации в доках не нашел, но встречался с такими примерами, как
   `News.active_objects.all()`

В чем отличие от использвания, к примеру **News.objects.all()**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К моделям в Django можно [прикрепить](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#model-attributes) сколько угодно нестандартных менеджеров. В данном случае это, видимо, менеджер, который отфильтровывает скрытые новости. Правда, я обычно делаю наоборот: переопределяю стандартный менеджер `objects`, а в админке использую какой-нибудь `all_objects`, таким образом пользователь точно не увидит, чего не нужно.